# doInBackground in AsyncTask for Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to know that if a `doInBackground` method of a `AsyncTask` calls a method, for example `XYZ()`, Is that method also executed asynchronously?

Can we make changes to the UI in XYZ() in such a situation? Will it make the UI unresponsive?

I have a method call in `doInBackground` which is network intensive and requires to download an image from the web. The UI becomes unresponsive as soon as the call to that method is made. Why?

```
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params)
        {

    String[] response = new String[2];
    Log.v("Background", "I am in background!");

    String url = params[0];
    String VoiceInput = params[1];
    IsCalledOnVoiceInput = VoiceInput;
    Log.v(url,url);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    try
    {

        HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(p);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                responseHandler);
        Log.v("Thread", responseBody);

        //Getting background image URL
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        JSONObject coords = reader.getJSONObject("coord");
        loc_latitude = coords.getString("lat");
        loc_longitude = coords.getString("lon");
        String imageURL="";
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        try
        {
            imageURL = getRandomImageURL(loc_latitude,loc_longitude);
            Log.v("Image URL as recieved from getRandomImageURL", imageURL);
            //Trying to convert Image from the above URL, get it and theh convert it to String
            URL urlOfTheImage = new URL(imageURL);

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlOfTheImage.openConnection().getInputStream());
            //Image successfully converted to string, ready to pass as a parameter!
            response[0] = "";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There seems to be a problem with the application. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Log.v("URL of Random Image",imageURL);

    }

    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    response[1] = responseBody;
    return response;
}
```

The method `getRandomImageURL` and all that code in the `try` block is network intensive. I can also provide its code.

Comment: Any method called in `doInBackground` will be called asynchronously. You shouldn't change the UI there.

Comment: Please post the appropriate section of your code.

Comment: Code added. Please overlook the comments in the code. Have I done something wrong in this code that makes the UI unresponsive for about 5 seconds at a minimum?

Comment: How are you executing the AsyncTask? Ensure that you're calling `execute()`, and not invoking `doInBackground()` directly.

Comment: `MyAsyncTask mat = new MyAsyncTask();            mat.execute(Url,IsCalledOnVoiceInput).get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: I just found out that if I get rid of the `.get(15, TimeUnit,SECONDS);` part. It works fine. But then how do I set a timeout?

Comment: See my answer for setting timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set time out like this...

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: One more thing, can we show toast messages from doInBackground? I am getting `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` and I think this is the cause? Am I right?

Comment: Yeah we cant in general. If you really need to show that you will have to do something like this. `Looper.prepare();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Looper.loop();`

Answer (score 2):

The code executing in the background is run in a separate thread.  Anything it does, including calling other methods, happens in that thread.  Since this is not the UI thread, it's not valid to make UI calls.  You have to post messages to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, whatever you call within doInBackgroud will run asynchronously. And no you shoudn't update UI from background thread for that you have CallBackDefined(onPostExecute). Or if UI update is require you can use runOnUIThread(...) API

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes to the UI only from the UI thread. In general the doInBackground() is for lengthy operations that do not update the UI or access the UI toolkit. You can periodically publish changes in state that need to be reflected in the UI (eg progress bar showing status of a download operation) by calling publishProgress().